# In Maven: how to attach sources to tools.jar

Tags: eclipse, maven-2, java, tools.jar

I have to use libraries in tools.jar and have therefor added this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.0</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>${java.home}/../lib/tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
```

Now I would like to attach the sources in Eclipse, so I see what I develop against.
I guess nothing will be available in the standard maven repositories (I can't even find anything in [download.java.net/com/sun](http://download.java.net/maven/2/com/sun/)).

I know there is a [source archive available](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/), but it contains everything and I would at least need to know what parts of it need to go in the source jar.

Has someone done this? Is there a tools-sources.jar available somewhere? Or can you tell me what parts of the jdk sources I need?

Comment: Good question. Didn't realize this could be complicated.

Comment: Seems like I am a specialist for asking questions no one can answer :-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's what I did. I downloaded the [source archive from openjdk](http://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk6/), extracted it and manually linked the jar source to

```
External Folder -> [unpacked archive basedir]/langtools/src/share/classes
```

This is not a maven solution, it's eclipse only, but it works.

Comment: This works for IntelliJ too! In a class in tools.jar (`FieldDoc`), clicked on the `Attach Sources` and browsed to `openjdk-6-src-b27-26_oct_2012.tar\langtools\src\share\classes`.